# How to display a plot in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am new in PyQt5 and I am trying to develop an app that should be able to load a file and display the file's information and create a plot.
I used the PyQt5 design to design the app.
This is the code created by PyQt5 design:

```
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>500</width>
    <height>350</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>500</width>
    <height>350</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>500</width>
    <height>350</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>421</width>
      <height>311</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="load_file">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(206, 0, 13);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Load file</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="plot">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(39, 167, 70);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Plot</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView"/>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

There are two buttons in the app, one to load a file and another one to display a plot. I can load the file but when I press the "Plot" button I need to load the file again.
I want to load the file and then be able to press the "Plot" button to show the plot. I also would like to display in the app the data that is inside the file. I used a ViewTable Widget but I don't know how to use it to do what I am looking for. Any idea?
This is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def load():
    load = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
    file = pd.read_csv(load, sep=';', decimal=',')
    return file

def plot():
    x = load()['time']
    y = load()['distance']
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ui = uic.loadUi('test_file.ui')

ui.load_file.clicked.connect(load)
ui.plot.clicked.connect(plot)

ui.show()
app.exec()
```

I am using this data just to test.

| time | distance |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 65 |
| 2 | 143 |
| 3 | 212 |
| 4 | 298 |
| 5 | 368 |

Comment: You might use
`from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas`
`from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar`
and then place your matplotlib figures therein

Comment: I think that I don't need more libraries because I already can show the plot. The problem is that when I press the "Plot" button I need to load the file twice until the plot be shown and even after that the app is always requesting to load the file. I think that I need to upload the file and somehow "save" it to use it (and create the plot) but I don't know how to do that